# Access to 'inner' classes in case of composition

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, composition

I have certain functionality encapsulated in classes which I use in another class. I think this is called composition.

```
class DoesSomething01
{
    public:
        DoesSomething01();
        void functionality01();
        void functionality02();
};

class DoesSomething02
{
    public:
        DoesSomething02();
        void functionality01();
        void functionality02();
};

class ClassA
{
    public:
        ClassA();

    private:
        DoesSomething01 *m_doesSomething01;
        DoesSomething02 *m_doesSomething02;
};
```

If I have now a `ClassB` which "knows" `ClassA` and have to use/execute `functionality01` and/or `functionality02` of classes `DoesSomething01` and/or `DoesSomething02` I see two possibilities:

a) Add methods like this to `ClassA` to provide `ClassB` direct access to `DoesSomething01` and/or `DoesSomething02`:

```
DoesSomething01 *getDoesSomething01() { return *m_doesSomething01; }
DoesSomething02 *getDoesSomething02() { return *m_doesSomething02; }
```

`ClassB` could then do something like this:

```
m_classA->getDoesSomething01()->functionality01();
```

b) Add (in this case four) methods to `ClassA` which forwards the method calls to `DoesSomething01` and `DoesSomething02` like this:

```
void doesSomething01Functionality01() { m_doesSomething01->functionality01(); }
void doesSomething01Functionality02() { m_doesSomething01->functionality02(); }
void doesSomething02Functionality01() { m_doesSomething02->functionality01(); }
void doesSomething02Functionality02() { m_doesSomething02->functionality02(); }
```

Which option is better and why?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each option?

Comment: `getDoesSomthing01()` and `getDoesSomthing02()` must/should return a pointer: `DoesSomthing01* getDoesSomthing01() { return m_doesSomthing01; }`

Comment: Of course, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

First option can be considered a code smell. According to Robert C. Martin's ['Clean Code'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) it is "Transitive Navigation" and should be avoided. Quoting the author:

> In general we don’t want a single module to know much about its
>   collaborators. More specifically, if A collaborates with B, and B
>   collaborates with C, we don’t want modules that use A to know about C.
>   (For example, we don’t want a.getB().getC().doSomething();.)

Second option looks better. It is classical use of [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern. And it is better, because it hides other functionalities of classes `DoesSomthing01` and `DoesSomthing02`.  Then you ve'got simplified view of it which is easier to use than 1st option.

Edit: there is also one more thing. You've got two classes which have the same functionalites and are aggregated by other class. You should consider using [Stratey pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) here. The your code will look like this:

```
class DoesSomething 
{
    public:
        virtual void functionality01() = 0;
        virtual void functionality02() = 0;
}

class DoesSomething01 : DoesSomething 
{
    public:
        DoesSomething01();
        void functionality01();
        void functionality02();
};

class DoesSomething02 : DoesSomething 
{
    public:
        DoesSomething02();
        void functionality01();
        void functionality02();
};

class ClassA
{
    public:
        ClassA();
       DoesSomething* doesSomething();                         // Getter
       void doesSomething(DoesSomething* newDoesSomething);    // Setter
       // ...

    private:
        DoesSomething *m_doesSomething;
};
```

Then you will need only two method instead of four:

```
void doesFunctionality01() { m_doesSomething->functionality01(); }
void doesFunctionality02() { m_doesSomething->functionality02(); }
```

Comment: Regarding transitive navigation: without knowing the concrete use case of the code, you could also argue that using a fluent interface is advised.

Answer (score 1):

The first scenario is a violation of law of Demeter, which says that a class can only talk to its immediate friends. Basically the problem with the first approach is that any change in the inner classes  DoSomething01 and DoSomething02 will trigger a change in Class A as well as Class B because both classes are now directly dependent on these inner classes.

The second option is better as it encapsulates the class B from inner classes  but a side effect of this solution is that now class A has a lot of methods that does nothing fancy except for delegating to its inner classes. This is fine but imagine if DoSomething01 has an inner class DoSomething03 and class B needs to access its functionality without directly knowing about it than the class A would need to have another method that would delegate to DoSomething01 that would in turn delegate to DoSomething03. In this case I think it is better to let class B directly know about DoSomething01 otherwise class A is going to have a huge interface that simply delegates to its inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

If there are many classes and/or many methods to be called it makes sense to invent 
an interface in the form of an abstract parent class:

```
class SomeInterface
{
    public:
    SomeInterface(){}

    virtual void functionally01() = 0;
    virtual void functionally02() = 0;
}
```

DoesSomthing01 and other classes would then inherit this class:

```
class DoesSomthing01 : public SomeInterface
```

and implement the methods.

If it make sense to associate a key with the instantiation of such a class
you could store these objects in ClassA e.g. using a map (here I 
use an integer as the key):

```
class ClassA
{
private:
    std::map<int, SomeInterface*> m_Interfaces;

public:
    SomeInterface* getInterface(const int key) 
    {
        std::map<int, SomeInterface*>::iterator it(m_Interfaces.find(key));
        if (it != m_Interfaces.end())
            return it->second;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
};
```

From ClassB you could then access them

```
int somekey = ...;
SomeInterface *myInter = m_classA->getInterface(somekey);
if (myInter)
    myInter->functionally01();
```

This way you have just one access method (getInterface()) independent 
of the number of objects.

In order to encode the access to the methods using a key you could
create a map which maps a key onto a closure or a simple switch statement:
in SomeInterface:

```
public:
   void executeMethod(const int key)
   {
       switch(key)
       {
           case 1: functionally01(); break;
           case 2: functionally01(); break;
           default:
               // error
   }


int methodKey = ...;
int objectKey = ...;
SomeInterface *myInter = m_classA->getInterface(objectKey);
if (myInter)
    myInter->executeMethod(methodKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good case for a Mediator Pattern.

This pattern manage communication between 2 objects that he owns.